# a puzzle on probability theory.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable.I want to prove:

$E[x]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P[X > x]dx}$...(*)

Here is my proof.let $f$ be the PDF(probability density function) of $X$.$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P[X > x]dx}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(1-\int_{-\infty}^{x}{f(t)dt)}dx}$.For the right hand size,we integral by part.

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{(1-\int_{-\infty}^{x}{f(t)dt)}dx}=(x-x\int_{-\infty}^{x}{f(t)dt})\mid_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf(x)dx$.Since the first item $(x-x\int_{-\infty}^{x}{f(t)dt})\mid_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ equals zero,we have proved $E[x]=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{P[X > x]dx}$.

However I find my proof is $\textbf{WRONG}$ because PDF $f\quad\textbf{May Not be continous}$.How can I handle this case?Is (*) always right,or exists some counterexample?Well I am not good at probability theory,I search for help.

Comment: If $X$ is non-negative then $\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_0^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>x)\;dx$, but I don't think the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>x)\;dx$ will converge in general.

Comment: Why,would you elaborate it?thanks...

Comment: Just try a simple example, say $X=\pm 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ each. $\mathbb{P}(X>x)=1$ for all $x<-1$.